# reverse Google image search from the CLI

Tags: linux, bash, thunar

Is it possible to do a reverse Google image search from the command line or a thunar custom action that only appears for images?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, at the moment, no. For normal searches, there is the possibility to use `googler` from the CLI, but it does not seem to support searching by image.

Google's API support for image search is a bit on/off. At the moment, there seems to be some support (https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/2630972?hl=en&ctx=topic&topic=2568895), but you will also find a lot of deprecated interfaces.

You might want to subscribe to stackoverflow's tag `google-apps-script` to follow the latest developments.